# why passing an identifier to @size annotated method not working?

Tags: java, android, annotations, java-annotations

this is the problem I'm trying to solve.

```
TextView[] containers=new TextView[2];
```

and I am calling following mehtod.

```
compeletLogin(containers);
```

and following is the method declaration.

```
 private void compeletLogin(@Size(2) TextView[] containers) {
    mEditTextName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mEditTextPass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mButtonLogin.animate().translationY(200);
    mButtonLogin.setText(R.string.logout);
    mImageProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mTextViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mTextViewName.setText(name);
    for (TextView tv: containers){
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

but when I am increasing length of array it's not giving me any error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK `@Size` only works on collection or array of primitive datatypes like `int`, `float`, `double`, `long` and `String`.

It doesn't work for Objects like `TextView`

Comment: it is not clearly said in the documentation.    ` The @Size annotation checks the size of a collection or array, as well as the length of a string. The @Size annotation can be used to verify the following qualities:`

Comment: @UrvishranaU yes. The document doesn't highlight it. I have tried it out and seems only works with primitive type collections. You can also try with primitive type and it will work as expected

Comment: but when I'm passing a formal argument as any identifier it won't work. e.g `void dosomthing(@Size(2) int[] data){}` and i'm calling with `dosomthing(new int[3])` works fine but when i do this `int[] data=new int[3]` and then passing it to 'dosmthing(data)`  won't show me any warning or error.!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@Size(max=2)` in place of `@Size(2)`